# Why would I get an AttributeError here if I provide an if statement to get around it?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've been inspired by the code here: https://towardsdatascience.com/stock-news-sentiment-analysis-with-python-193d4b4378d4

I'm basically scraping news from a financial website using Beautiful Soup. This particular flavor of the code I made is where I'm stumped:

```
for i, table_row in enumerate(df_tr): 
    if table_row.a.text is not None: 
        print(table_row.a.text)
```

I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

But I literally provide an if statement that says if that table_row is None, it wont reach the print statement. I even did a version where I put an else statement that tells it to `continue` and I still get the same error. Why is this?

Comment: You haven't provided an if statement that says 'if that table_row is None'. You provided an if statement that says 'if table_row.a.text is not None'. In order to evaluate that statement, python must investigate the value in table_row.a.text. table_row.a is obviously None and hence the error trying to read table_row.a.text. This error occurs in the if statement not the print statement. change it to: if table_row.a is not None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **`if table_row.a is not None:`** instead, since `table_row.a` is the *"'NoneType' object"* mentioned in the error.

> ```py
>     if table_row.a.text is not None:
>         print(table_row.a.text)
> ```

You've just shifted the error from the *`print...`* line to the *`if...`* line, since the **`.text`** part is what raised the error.

---

> I even did a version where I put an else statement that tells it to `continue` and I still get the same error

You probably tried something like *`if table_row.a.text is None: continue`*, but same issue there - it should be

```py
for i, table_row in enumerate(df_tr): 
    if not table_row.a: continue
    print(table_row.a.text)
```